# Newly added items in lists is not re-rendering component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

after every request to Add/Delete/Sell item with socket.io, function refreshItems() is called, which just setState to new items from database. Everything working fine but sometimes after adding 6-7 items, table is not refreshing. Item is added, I can see it in database and after refresh page. Any ideas where problem can come from? 
There is github for project; https://github.com/przemekkijak/hypehub/tree/refactor

```js
      function refreshItems() {
        socket.emit('getCurrentItems', data => {
          setCurrent(data);
        })
        socket.emit('getSoldItems', data => {
          setSold(data);
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is an async function, use callback function in setState and update the state.

Like this.

```
function refreshItems() {
        socket.emit('getCurrentItems', data => {
          setCurrent( pre => data);
        })
        socket.emit('getSoldItems', data => {
          setSold(pre => data);
        })
      }
```

Comment: But why there is a problem with refresh? Mod changed my title and it's saying something different. My items are adding so refreshItems() is working, but after random amount of items added, when I try to add another one he is not showing. I have to refresh page or add another item, then 2 of them shows.

Comment: Because when you add item randomly the state get corrupted, as it is an async function and many concurrent update making the state unpredictable so it is recommended to use callback to the state.

Comment: So it should go like this?     getCurrentItems', data => {
          setCurrent(prevState => {
            return data;
          });
        })

Comment: Or even without return?

Comment: if you use brackets then it's must to add return statement, and if you don't use brackets then return is not required. 
These both are same. `setCurrent(prevState => { return data; });`  and `setCurrent(prevState => data; );`

Comment: Okay so I did it and problem is still existing. 5-6 items added fine, 7th not showing, only after refresh. Could you look at my code? RefreshItems is in app.js

Comment: Oh I saw something, maybe this will help. When I am adding items eg. [1,2,3,4,5] and I am trying to add 6th and it is not showing, and then I add next item for example '7', and after adding 7, only 6th is showing, to see 7th item I have to refresh or add 8 item

Comment: what `key` are you using in the  render items ?

Comment: Okay I read some docs and I finally understand why there is it problem, and what does that mean that setState is async. I will try to figure it out on my own but if you have any suggestions, would be great

Comment: Yes correct, But when we use setState with callback it should render the update items correctly . try this `setCurrent( pre => [...pre, ...data]);`

Comment: Can't be like that, my data is returned as array filled with items, so in that case I got error "Encountered two children with the same key, `342`. Keys should be unique" because in tab are previous items and new items

Comment: by the way, what does [... <- it mean? I mean dots

Comment: It's array destructuring assignment. you can read more about this on MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment